# Store the value of objects instead of a reference to the object itself

Tags: python, django

I've hit an interesting problem that I know must have a simple solution, but I'm at a loss. I have a model with a field "priority_score" that changes every day. I want to forecast which model will have the highest priority_score on any given day in the next two weeks.

```
WEEK = 'WE'
MONTH = 'MO'
QUARTER = 'QU'
TIME_PERIOD_CHOICES = (
    (WEEK, 'Week'),
    (MONTH, 'Month'),
    (QUARTER, 'Quarter'),
)
class Exercise(models.Model):
    priority_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3, editable=False, default = 0)
    frequency = models.IntegerField()
    time_period = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TIME_PERIOD_CHOICES,default=WEEK)
```

There are a few other factors that affect how any given object's priority_score will change. I'll skip this detail, but in general, I'm iterating 14 times (once per every day over the next two weeks) to determine what the highest priority_score is.

```
time_period = {
    "WE" : 7,
    "MO" : 30,
    "QU" : 90,
}
days_to_forecast = 14
recommendations = []
exercise_list = Exercise.objects.all()
for i in range(0, days_to_forecast-1):
    queryset = sorted(
        chain(exercise_list),
        key=attrgetter('priority_score'),
        reverse=True)

    recommendations.append(queryset)
    print i
    print queryset[0]
    print queryset[0].priority_score
    print ""

    queryset[0].priority_score = 0
    for obj in queryset:
        priority_iteration = Decimal(float(obj.frequency) / time_period[obj.time_period])
        obj.priority_score = obj.priority_score + priority_iteration
```

The output of the print statements are an accurate reflection of the object with the highest priority_score on each date as well as the priority_score for that object on that date.

What I'm trying to do though is to store the sorted results per day and show that in a template. In each iteration, I'm storing the new queryset in the recommendations list. But when I display the final output of recommendations, it is instead displaying the latest "results" (priority scores) for each object, not the priority scores as of a specific iteration over a two week period.

I believe what's happening is that recommendations is only storing a reference to the object, not the values themselves. So when I fetch the results for recommendations, it is then resolving the query and only showing the end result of each object, not the result at the time I appended the queryset to the recommendations list.

How can I store the result of each iteration of the loop into an object that can then be referenced at the end of the entire loop?

**Update**
I've isolated the issue to this section:

```
queryset = sorted(
    chain(exercise_list),
    key=attrgetter('priority_score'),
    reverse=True)
```

It seems that if I just say queryset = exercise_list, I wouldn't have this issue. But somehow, using sorted(), the output of my recommendations change as querset values change

Comment: Converting `execute_list` to a list before entering the iteration should work, right?

Comment: Perhaps. I will try that. Question though. Will converting to a list still allow me to access other attributes attached to that original object? For instance, in my loop, I'm also attaching ancillary objects which each have their own priority score. Meaning I can get a result for queryset[0].priority_score as well as queryset[0].workout[0].priority_score. Will converting to a list still let me get this second value?

Comment: I think you should still get the objects. The only thing we're changing by converting it to a list is executing/evaluating the queryset before entering the loop.

Comment: So next question, how does one convert a query to a list?

Comment: exercise_list = list(Exercise.objects.all()). A word of warning though. If the table is huge this is a very slow way to do it.

Comment: Gave it a try, but it didn't work. recommendations.append(list(queryset)). Maybe list() is forcing the query to evaluate at time of iteration but the code is still storing the relationship between the variable and the query rather than storing the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the technical aspects of sorted(), but I believe that this function doesn't return an actual object but rather a reference to the object. Therefore, when any updates are made, they are traced back to the original source (in this case, the original exercise_list). So any variable based on the original exercise_list is automatically updated when django resolves the variable to values.

To retain the values that are current as of variable declaration, a copy must be made

```
import copy

queryset = sorted(
    chain(exercise_list),
    key=attrgetter('priority_score'),
    reverse=True)
newobj = copy.deepcopy(queryset)
recommendations.append(newobj)
```

These values stored in recommendations will not update when queryset values are changed.